# How to make transition work with "visibility" but not "display"?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

The `transition` element of vue only works with `display:none` but not `visibility:hidden`, is there any way to make it work with `visibility`? I want to get the `clientWidth` of the element before it shows up, with `display:none` I can't get that value.

By the way I'm using vue3.

Here is the reproduction demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-hermann-b1s5q

Comment: could you provide some code in codesanbox, you could fork this one https://codesandbox.io/s/late-framework-96c0g?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: maybe if you force it with css: `div{ display:block !important; }` ?

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim Thanks, I have updated my question.

Comment: Transitions are applied when an element is inserted or removed from the DOM. What do you need the elements' `clientWidth` for?

Comment: There's likely a workaround where you can get it's width when rendered, assuming you don't need it on page-load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume, for the sake of argument, that you genuinely do need to use `visibility` for hiding and that other potential solutions (such as `opacity`) won't work in your real use case, possibly because they don't prevent user interactions with the element.

However, the assertion in the question is slightly misleading. It isn't really a difference between `display` and `visibility`. The real difference here is that the `display` case is using `v-show`, which includes special handling for transitions.

The current source code for `v-show` can be seen here:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/d7beea015bdb208d89a2352a5d43cc1913f87337/packages/runtime-dom/src/directives/vShow.ts

A similar approach can be used to construct a directive that uses `visibility`. Below is an example. It is based on the code for `v-show` but I've cut it back to just the code required for this particular use case:

```js
const visible = {
  updated(el, { value, oldValue }, { transition }) {
    if (!value === !oldValue) {
      return
    }

    if (value) {
      transition.beforeEnter(el)
      el.style.visibility = ''
      transition.enter(el)
    } else {
      transition.leave(el, () => {
        el.style.visibility = 'hidden'
      })
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      show: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.show = !this.show;
    }
  },
  directives: {
    visible
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
#app {
  text-align: center;
}

.tooltip-enter-active {
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}

.tooltip-leave-active {
  transition: transform 0.35s ease-in, opacity 0.28s ease-out;
}

.tooltip-enter-from {
  transition: none;
}

.tooltip-enter-from,
.tooltip-leave-to {
  transform: translateY(-30px) scale(0.96);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.2/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <transition name="tooltip">
    <div v-visible="show">
      Using visibility
    </div>
  </transition>
  <button @click="toggle">toggle message</button>
</div>
```

I did also have to make a small CSS change to give the enter transition a kick:

```css
.tooltip-enter-from {
  transition: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Actually I did the similar solution as yours, but the animation was jerky, I can't figure out the reason until I see your  `.tooltip-enter-from` ! Thanks really!

Comment: How can you access that transition object in the update function in Vue 2? I can't find anything in the docs

Comment: Update: I had to change `updated` to `update` and the third argument is named `vnode` which contains `vnode.data.transition`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off without `<transition>` in this case:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      show: true,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      const tooltip = this.$refs.tooltip;

      this.show = !this.show;
      tooltip.classList.toggle("tooltip-show");
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Tooltip-width: ', this.$refs.tooltip.clientWidth);
  },
});

app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-30px) scale(0.96);
  transition: transform 0.35s, opacity 0.25s;
}

.tooltip-show {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.2/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="tooltip" ref="tooltip">This will work!</div>
  <button @click="toggle">toggle tooltip</button>
</div>
```